# What hardware to purchase for MySQL server? Details below

Tags: mysql, hardware

I am planning to build a basic server machine dedicated to running MySQL for my small business.

What I need the database for...

I will be setting up a database to hold records of registered voters in various states for business purposes. Each table will contain the records for registered voters in one state. The average number of records for each table will be approximately 6 to 7 million records. But the largest one will be approximately 17 million records.

I will only be doing 2 things with these tables. Querying them to search for a single record, then marking that record in a separate field to indicate that the record has been found.

I will have an average of 10 to 20 users (but as many as 100 users) simultaneously running the aforementioned queries. This should result in as few as 100 queries per hour, or as many as 10,000 queries per hour.

These queries need to return results as quickly as possible. Preferably in less than 1 second. Or even close to instantaneous as a user is typing in a search box on the front end.

I need to know what kind of hardware resources I should purchase with the above requirements in mind. What kind of cpu? How many cpus? How many cores? How much ram? How much disk space? How many drives? What kind of drives? Raid configuration? Also, how much internet bandwidth should I need?

Thanks for helping out a noob.

Answer (score 1):

This is really tiny. Test it on a machine you have already. Index the right fields and you should get significantly better than 1 second even on very basic hardware.

cpus - 1 - you are never going to be executing more than a query at once based on usage described

RAM 2G+, but probably not more than 6. Depends a bit on table index types.

Raid - basic low end mirror (RAID1).

Bandwidth - not much at all. You could do this on 64kbps probably.

On a small business, I wouldn't by buying hardware. Use a cloud service if the terms of data usage allows it.

Answer (score 1):

10K queries/hour = 4/sec -- no problem in any situation.  This assumes you can readily locate a row, and don't need to scan for it.  Without this.  With a "unique" key, performance is no problem.  With no useful key, no server can handle your task.

On the good end of the above, 1 second is easy; even 0.1 second is likely.  (At that point, the client software, network, etc becomes a factor.  But those should not be an issue either.

The disk requirement is about 17GB -- easy to purchase.  So get at least 40GB of disk space.  Any kind of disk; 1 drive, no RAID.

One table per state -- wrong design.  Instead have a column with the 2-letter state code (`CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii`).

If you average 30K updates per day, it might take 6,000 days (24 years!) to update all the rows.  Might this be a problem?

CPU and cores -- Ignore; this is almost never an issue in using MySQL.

RAM -- 4GB is fine.  Even 2G is OK.  You will be I/O-bound, but even a hard disk can maintain something like 100 queries per second.

Network -- probably the cheapest will suffice.

A cloud service will be both cheap and provide a lot of services you have not mentioned, such as backup and recovery.  Their price will include power, network access, etc.  They will give you a fraction of a machine.

I think your most critical thing to worry about now is how to identify the row to update.  Once you have that, we should discuss indexing.  *That* is critical to making the rest viable.  Oh, and the 24 year estimate!

**More**

I like using `AJAX` behind a `<button...>` to update the record.  It may decrease the *user* time to "update" to less than one second for the "user".  (And I already included the SQL time above.)

It would not surprise me if "voter ids" vary drastically between states.  If a single datatype (probably `VARCHAR(33)`) does not work well, I will retract my insistence that all the data be in a single table.  (Performance is essentially the same either way.)

If the "user" needs to scan several entries to pick one, then we need to discuss the query that lists the possibilities.  Would it include multiple probes into the 17M rows based on approximate spellings, different spacing or capitalization, etc?  *This* may be your Achilles heel!  (And I would be happy to discuss it.)

I gather that the "user" is picking from a list of possible entries?  What happens if none of of them "match"?

Comment: Thanks for the input. To clear up a couple of your concerns... Yes, there is a unique key. The raw data I obtain from the state election office has voter ID numbers that are unique. Also, I should clarify the information that will be updated in the records. Basically, as my employees are querying records, about 75% of the time, they'll be marking a record as "found". This will be done manually once the employee finds the correct record. This will be done by way of a button on the front end that triggers an update to a field that should be a simple yes no entry to that record's field.

Comment: I added some "more".